# jQuery General function to get value of :input selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selector

Is there a way to get the value of an `:input` in jQuery that holds for all `:input`?

I am asking this because I have a page with `select` and `checkbox`, it is for the following code:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        var localArgument = arguments[i].trim();
        data[localArgument] = $(html).find(":input[name='" + localArgument + "']").val();
        $(html).on("change", ":input[name='" + localArgument + "']", function(event) {
            console.log(localArgument + ": " + $(this).val());
            data[localArgument] = $(this).val();
            reloadTable(table, html, data);
        });
    }
```

Where `arguments` is an array that holds names for elements.

I know I need to do it for `checkbox` with `.prop("checked")`, however I would much rather use a general function which I know does not need to be updated in the future.

Answer (score 0):

just use `$('input')` selector to select all `input` elements

If you want to get the value of each input element you can do something like

```
$('input').each(function() {
   // use $(this).val() to get the value
})
```

Comment: If you aren't looking for all `input`s, you can use the [JQuery Has Attribute Selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/), like this `$('input[name]')`!

Comment: This doesn't work for `input[type='checkbox']` as you need to use the `.prop('checked')` there.

Comment: @skiwi checkbox has a value as well. OP question was about retreiving values

Comment: It does work for `input[type='checkbox']`, as long as you select a checked checkbox (`input:checkbox:checked`), and provide the `value` attribute: `<input type="checkbox" value="foo" checked/>`, so it will be either `'foo'` or `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

You can safely use `val()` for all inputs, checkboxes, radio buttons, and selects.  This is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/FxjQB/3